# Unable to start cassandra server

Tags: apache-http-server

I tried to start cassandra server using `bin\cassandra.bat`.
It is giving me the following error [image: CassandraError]

Can someone please let me know the solution for the problem.
The issue is

> Failed to create parent directories for [C:\Program Files (x86)\cassandra\cassandra-3.11.4\logs\system.log]

Comment: Can someone please let me know the solution for the problem.   issue is  "Failed to create parent directories for [C:\Program Files (x86)\cassandra\cassandra-3.11.4\logs\system.log] "

Comment: Just a guess, but in Windows 7 and above `C:\Program Files` and `C:\Program Files (x86)` are restricted and do not typically allow programs to write files (such as logs) to those directories. You should try installing Cassandra somewhere else, into a folder you control (e.g. `C:\Programs\Cassandra`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run as administrator. Open windows menu, search for command prompt, right click, select run as administrator.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).